# how to set sizeLimit for multiple files in valum file uploader?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, size

I know that there is a property called sizeLimit: 10000000 in the js of the plugin, but I does not work for multiple files, just for each file uploaded, does someone know how to fix that? I mean like count each Mb file, I dont know what to do please help

Comment: why not limit each file upload to a max value to arrive at the total allowed max size for multiple files... say for each file upload max allowed size is 1 MB... then if you allow 5 uploads per person/post you get max allowed size for 5 uploads to be 5 Mb...